# Parse URL in php

Tags: php, url

In php, if I wanted to parse a URL, such as www.site.com/index.php?foo=bar, I can do with the _POST variable. I can retrieve `bar` by `_POST['foo']`.

But what if my URL is something like `www.site.com/index.php?foo&bar`. i.e., I don't have the arguments as key-value pairs as in the first case. How to parse this in php?

Comment: have you tried `var_dump`'ing `$_POST` before asking? What did you find? Also, what makes you think that `/index.php?foo=bar` would populate `$_POST` in the first place? POST data is not submitted in the URL but in the Request body. The arguments submitted through the URL are in `$_GET`.

Comment: Gordon, First of all, I am new to PHP. I am learning it only now as I progress with my work. I tried paser_url in php. Even that is somethign similar to _POST. From what you have said, I searched var_dump now. Thanks.

Comment: Gordon's remark wasn't about using var_dump, but rather that for GET requests (ie. with arguments in the URI), you should use the $_GET superglobal array. For POST requests (ie. posting a form with method="post") you would use the $_POST superglobal array instead.

Comment: I think he's trying to parse a URL other than the current one.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url).

Quoted from php.net:

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array
> containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.
>
> This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks
> it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted,
> parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly.

Then, use [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse the query parameters part.

> Parses str as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets
> variables in the current scope.
> To get the current QUERY_STRING, you may use the variable $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. Also, you may want to read the section on
> variables from external sources.
> The magic_quotes_gpc setting affects the output of this function, as parse_str() uses the same mechanism that PHP uses to populate the
> $_GET, $_POST, etc. variables.

```
<?php 
  $parts = parse_url('www.site.com/index.php?foo&bar');
  print_r($parts);
  // Array ( [path] => www.site.com/index.php [query] => foo&bar )


  parse_str ($parts['query'], $query);
  print_r($query);
  // Array ( [foo] => [bar] => ) 
 
 // Alternately you can do this in a single shot like below:
 parse_str(parse_url('www.site.com/index.php?foo&bar', PHP_URL_QUERY));

?>
```

Comment: I thought it was a great answer.  Too lazy to try to find it on php.net directly.  :) +1 from me.

Comment: Edit: perhaps you should have mentioned that the "alternative" version sets variables in the current scope.  If you add $query to parse_str then the effect is the same as the first example.

Answer (score 2):

It's a misconception that requesting a URL like

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?foo=bar
```

would give you `bar` in `$_POST['bar']`. Url parameters will populate `$_GET`. Anything that's supposed to show up in `$_POST` has to be submitted in the Request body. See [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) for some details.

With that clarified, empty URL parameters are not a problem at all. A URL like

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?foo&bar
```

will populate `$_GET['foo']` and `$_GET['bar']` with empty values.