# Using PHP to split url

Tags: php, split

I'm trying to split my url and have them in two variables.

For Example:

url = https://example.com/page@01

I want to be able split this url into two and create two variable.

```
$part_1 = example.com;
$part_2 = page@01
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look at `parse_url`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.com. Have you done any research on the topic yourself or have you tried anything already? Please post your efforts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810577/parse-url-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can also use explode()

```
$a = "https://example.com/page@01";
$b = explode('/', $a);
$part_1 = $b[2];
$part_2 = $b[3];
print_r($part_1); 
echo '<br>';
print_r($part_2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `parse_url` function to split url into components.

```
$data = parse_url('https://example.com/page@01');
print_r($data);
```

Output:

> Array ( [scheme] => https [host] => example.com [path] => /page@01 )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER`, with which you can retrieve various information regarding script headers, paths, and locations, including the URL, by following the example below:

```
URL = https://example.com/page@01

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = /page@01
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = example.com
```

---

Reference: [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php)